# Python: Variable in Loop error

Tags: python, loops, variables

I am Trying to simplify my program but it says "invalid syntax" on the "=" in

```
"B=tkinter.Button(start, text=x)"
```

Code

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
start = tkinter.Tk()
for x in ["New","Load"]:(
    B=tkinter.Button(start, text=x)
    B.pack()
    )
#N = tkinter.Button(start, text="New")
#L = tkinter.Button(start, text="Load")
#N.pack()
#L.pack()
start.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why do you surround B declaration by parenthesis ?

Comment: What's with the parenthesis after the `for`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't put parentheses around an assignment because assignments are not expressions, they don't evaluate to anything nor do they return a value.

```
>>> (x=1)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    (x=1)
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```